# Legend not working for live data and while loop configuration

Tags: matplotlib, while-loop, label, legend, gpio

My code takes a continuously updating input from raspberry pi, which is then plotted onto a graph. I'm trying to use the legend to display the current frequency (most recent output of y_data) however I can't seem to get it to display. Placing `plt.legend()` just before `plt.show()` results in a display, however freezing of the graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib  
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')  
from matplotlib.figure import Figure  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  
import numpy as np  

x_data = []  
y_data = []

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)              
INPUT_PIN = 26                       
GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
line, = plt.plot([],[], 'k-',label = 'data', drawstyle = 'steps')  
avr, = plt.plot([],[], 'g--',label = 'mean')  
plt.show(block = False)  

def update(x_data, y_data, average):

    line.set_ydata(y_data)
    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    avr.set_xdata(x_data)
    avr.set_ydata([average]*len(x_data))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
    ax.draw_artist(line)
    ax.draw_artist(avr)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    data = round(y_data[-1], 1)
    ax.legend((line, avr), (data, 'mean'))
    fig.canvas.update()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

while True:                             #Begin continuous loop
    NUM_CYCLES = 10                     #Loops to be averaged over
    start = time.time()
    for impulse_count in range(NUM_CYCLES):
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
    duration = time.time() - start      #seconds to run for loop

    frequency = NUM_CYCLES / duration   #Frequency in Hz
    bpm = (frequency/1000)*60           #Frequency / no. of cogs per breath * min

    x_data.append(time.time())  #add new data to data lists
    y_data.append(bpm)             

    average = sum(y_data)/float(len(y_data))
    update(x_data,y_data, average)       #call function to update graph contents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call `fig.canvas.draw()` at the end of the update function, not in the middle of it. I'm not sure why you add all the artists again in the update function, so you may leave that out. Concerning the legend, It's probably best to create it once at the beginning and inside the update function only update the relevant text.

Commenting out all the GPIO stuff, this is a version which works fine for me:

```
import matplotlib  
#matplotlib.use('qt5agg')  
from matplotlib.figure import Figure  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  
import numpy as np  

x_data = []  
y_data = []

#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)              
#INPUT_PIN = 26                       
#GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
line, = plt.plot([],[], 'k-',label = 'data', drawstyle = 'steps')  
avr, = plt.plot([],[], 'g--',label = 'mean')
# add legend already at the beginning
legend = ax.legend((line, avr), (0.0, 'mean'))  
plt.show(block = False)  

def update(x_data, y_data, average):

    line.set_ydata(y_data)
    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    avr.set_xdata(x_data)
    avr.set_ydata([average]*len(x_data))
    #fig.canvas.draw()  <- use this at the end
    #ax.draw_artist(ax.patch) # useless?
    #ax.draw_artist(line)     # useless?
    #ax.draw_artist(avr)      # useless?

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    data = round(y_data[-1], 1)
    # only update legend here
    legend.get_texts()[0].set_text(str(data))

    #fig.canvas.update() # <- what is this one needed for?
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()


while True:                             #Begin continuous loop
    NUM_CYCLES = 10                     #Loops to be averaged over
    start = time.time()
    #for impulse_count in range(NUM_CYCLES):
    #    GPIO.wait_for_edge(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
    a = np.random.rand(700,800) # <- just something that takes a little time

    duration = time.time() - start      #seconds to run for loop

    frequency = NUM_CYCLES / duration   #Frequency in Hz
    bpm = (frequency/1000)*60           #Frequency / no. of cogs per breath * min

    x_data.append(time.time())  #add new data to data lists
    y_data.append(bpm)             

    average = sum(y_data)/float(len(y_data))
    update(x_data,y_data, average)       #call function to update graph contents
```

Comment: Everything does run, however I need my 'data' value in my legend to be a continuously updating value for frequency. Set_text gives me the string 'data' rather than the number calculated just before it

Comment: Alternatively, if there was a way to display a continuously updating section of text that doesn't need to use the legend function that would be excellent.

Comment: The line `legend.get_texts()[0].set_text(str(data))`  does exactly what you need, i.e. showing the last value in `y_data` rounded to one decimal place in the legend. Since `set_text()` can handle float values you can leave out the `str` command if that makes you more comfortable. If you don't want a legend, but pure text, you can of course use the [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) command instead of a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Add `plt.draw()` (or `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` for a more OO approach) at the end of `update`.

Comment: Does that solve the problem of placing a legend into the figure?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It does for me. I did not change anything else other than removing `GPIO` stuff and replacing `GPIO.wait_for_edge` by `time.sleep`.

Comment: Fair enough. It didn't work for me, that's why I posted my answer. Maybe it's due to the `qt5agg` which I don't have.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, updating interactive plots in a loop may be tricky and depends on the exact matplotlib version, backend and other details.